# How to create an Active Record select query with an OR statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This should be quite simple, but I can't work out the syntax.

I have an AR query

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.select { |t| t != 'schema_migrations' }
```

that I want to add an OR statement to

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.select { |t| t != 'schema_migrations' OR 'pg_search_documents' }
```

What is the correct syntax? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.select { |t| t != 'schema_migrations' && t != 'pg_search_documents' }
```

The code inside the block is just a Ruby expression that needs to return a boolean result so you can use the logical AND operator `&&` to express the logic "table name is not 'schema_migrations' AND table name is not 'pg_search_documents'"

Perhaps a simpler way to express the same logic is to subtract an array of table names that you want to filter out like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables - ['schema_migrations', 'pg_search_documents']
```

Comment: Since he's asking for an OR, should it be a '||' instead of a '&&"?

Comment: I thought the same thing at first but I don't think that was the intention. Saying "table name is not x OR y" is logically equivalent to "table is not x AND table is not y".

Comment: thanks steve, this worked perfectly (sorry for the slow response).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reject pattern along with array `include?`, as it makes it easy to add more tables to the rejection list..

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.reject do |t| 
  %w(schema_migrations pg_search_documents).include?(t)
end
```

Comment: thanks kandadaboggu, this looks like it would work, and is a very readable format. For now I'm using Steve's solution, but may well switch to this when I get round to refactoring and cleaning up my code :)